# Проблема с работой с файлом (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пытаюсь имитировать работу сервера с помощью программы, считывающей из файла информацию, которую туда кладет программа-"клиент".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct user {
    int id;
    string nickname;
};

int main() {
    int n = 1;
    user* list = new user[n];
    fstream users("C://Users//Kompik 2.0//Desktop//New//Users.txt", ios::out);
    int KOSTIL = 0; 
    cout << "SERVER IS RUNNING..." << endl;
    while (true) {
        users.open("C://Users//Kompik 2.0//Desktop//New//Users.txt");
        users.seekg(0, ios::end);
        int prev_size = users.tellg();
        int size = prev_size;
        users.close();
        while (prev_size == size) {
            users.open("C://Users//Kompik 2.0//Desktop//New//Users.txt");
            users.seekg(0, ios::end);
            prev_size = users.tellg();
            users.close();
        }
//// --------------КОСТЫЛЬНЫЙ КОСТЫЛЬ----------------
//      if (KOSTIL == 1) {
//          string new_line;
//          getline(users, new_line);
//          string command = new_line.substr(0, new_line.find(' '));
//          /*if (command == "new") {
//              n++;
//              user* temp_list = new user[n];
//              for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
//                  temp_list[i] = list[i];
//              delete[] list;
//              list = new user[n];
//              for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
//                  list[i] = temp_list[i];
//              delete[] temp_list; 
//              list[n - 1].id = stoi(new_line.substr(new_line.find(' ') + 1, new_line.find(' ') + 3));
//              list[n - 1].nickname = new_line.substr(new_line.rfind(' ') + 1, new_line.length());
//              cout << "User " << list[n - 1].nickname << "has logged into the chat room" << endl;
//          }
//          if (command == "quit") {
//              n--;
//              int del_id = stoi(new_line.substr(new_line.find(' ') + 1, new_line.find(' ') + 3));
//              string del_nick = new_line.substr(new_line.rfind(' ') + 1, new_line.length());
//              user* temp_list = new user[n + 1];
//              int j = 0;
//              for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
//                  if (list[i].id != del_id) {
//                      temp_list[j] = list[i];
//                      j++;
//                  }
//              delete[] list;
//              list = new user[n];
//              for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
//                  list[i] = temp_list[i];
//              delete[] temp_list;
//              cout << "User " << del_nick << "has left the chat" << endl;
//          }
//          if (n != 1)
//              for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
//                  cout << list[i].id << ' ' << list[i].nickname << endl;*/
//          cout << command << endl;
//          cout << "CHANGED" << endl;
//      }
        if (KOSTIL == 1) {
            string line;
            getline(users, line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        KOSTIL = 1;
        cout << "CHANGED" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Алгоритм во внешнем цикле считывает количество бит в файле и затем во внутреннем цикле проверяет предыдущее количество бит с полученным для определения, изменился файл или нет. Проблема в том, что при первом проходе внешнего цикла по какой-то причине `tellg()` выдает -1. Из-за этого происходит сравнение -1 с 0. Внутренний цикл проскакивается, и программа "думает", что файл изменился, хотя он пуст. Затем все работает корректно.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: @AlexF По-хорошему я хотел, чтобы файл можно было и читать, и записывать в него информацию, чтобы другая программа считывала то, что ей надо. И стирание информации тоже часть плана, потому что мне хотелось, чтобы файл хранил только новую информацию, которую туда записывает эта программа и простая программа-"клиент".

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Исправил

Comment: Вы открываете файл на запись `fstream users("C://Users//Kompik 2.0//Desktop//New//Users.txt", ios::out);`. Конструктор не только создает объект fstream, но и сразу открывает файл. Если вы каждый раз в циклах вызываете `fstream users.open()`, то тогда создавайте поток без открытия файла `fstream users;`. И всегда проверяйте результат функций `open` - не всегда файловая система даст вам открыть файл. А поскольку в комментариях вы говорите о нескольких программах, работающих с одним файлом, то почитайте что-нибудь о многопоточном программировании.

Comment: @DmitryK Хорошо, спасибо большое.